# .htaccess Custom Redirect non "www" to "www" with params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to make this work with HTTP, HTTPS and SSL, this is my actual (working) rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But i Need to force to redirect the non "www" urls (like http://domain.com) to the same URL with the "www" AND still working the index.php?url=$1 because i need this for my "router" engine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work (before any other rewrite rule):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the non-www to www rule at the beginning, like this:

```
#non-www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```